# sed - "unknown command" when replacing pattern with contents of file

Tags: bash, sed, runtime-error

I try to manipulate some "templated" text files. Meaning that the files contain some "tokens" which need to be replaced by some actual strings - either hard coded, or readable from other files.

I have the following 2 lines:

```
    sed -r -e 's_<!-- cssintern -->_<style type="text/css">\n<!-- cssintern -->\n</style>\n_' -i "$out_dir_aca/books_1by1/independent/$(basename "$aca_frag").html"
    sed -e '^<!-- cssintern -->^' -e '{r '"$src_dir_frags_struct/styles1.css.frag" -e 'd}' -i "$out_dir_aca/books_1by1/independent/$(basename "$aca_frag").html"
```

The first one works fine. The problem is that the second one generates an "unkown command" error, and I ran out of ideas how to fix it. The debugging output is the following (error text on last line):

```
+ for aca_frag in $out_dir_aca/frags_1by1/*
+ '[' -f '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag' ']'
++ basename '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
+ echo '    09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
    09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag
+ cat '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/1_txt_in/##_frags_struct_##/doctypeXHTML.frag'
++ basename '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
+ cat '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/1_txt_in/##_frags_struct_##/head.frag'
++ basename '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
+ cat '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/1_txt_in/##_frags_struct_##/foot.frag'
++ basename '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
++ basename '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
+ sed -r -e 's_<!-- cssintern -->_<style type="text/css">\n<!-- cssintern -->\n</style>\n_' -i '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/books_1by1/independent/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag.html'
++ basename '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/frags_1by1/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag'
+ sed -re '^<!-- cssintern -->^' -re '{r /home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/1_txt_in/##_frags_struct_##/styles1.css.frag' -re 'd}' -i '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/books_1by1/independent/09.14 - Acatistul inaltarii Sfintei Cruci.frag.html'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `^'
```

I used for separators `^`, `_`, `/`, I played in "all" ways with simple and double quotation marks, and everything else that I found on the internet. Nothing changes the fact that the error remains.

In the past I used this line

```
sed.exe -i -e '/%%H/{r ..\/##_frags_##\/out\/%%H' -e 'd}' .\out\out.frag
```

in a Windows `cmd` script, and worked fine. (`%%H` references the name of the file, when parsing all the files in the folder with a `for`). I am actually rewriting the old scripts in Linux, as exercize - hopefully to add simplicity and extra features.

I intend to adapt the following `sed` command:

```
sed -e '/<TEXT1>/{r File1' -e 'd}' -i File2
```

to my particular needs.

**Note**: I provided the exact file names and paths, thinking that they might provide an insight.

**Note**: I use Debian 10.7 in a virtual machine.

**Note**: the script file starts with `#!/bin/bash -xv`. `-xv` is obviously used only when debugging, otherwise missing.

Comment: What do you expect the expression `-e '^<!-- cssintern -->^'` to do? I don't see a sed command there.

Comment: @larsks: I am not sure I understand your question. I try to implement the solution provided here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49438/383155. I ended up using `^` instead of `/`, but none of them works anyway. The `<!-- cssintern -->` is just a string, the "pattern". I tried using just `cssintern`, without any special characters, also without positive result.

Comment: `I ended up using ^ instead of /` How did you "end up" there? Go back. If you want to filter xml files use xml aware parser. It's not possible to parse xml with regex. `I intend to adapt the following` Then why did you change `/` to `^`? Change it back!

Comment: `-e '\^<!-- cssintern -->^'` would be a valid sed command. You need to tell sed you are using a different delimiter.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I "ended up" there when I gave up trying to find a delimiter which would work. I started with `/` and that failed, that is why  moved on to others. Going back without other modification is going to be futile (I already tried, as a result of your comment). *" It's not possible to parse xml with regex."* - that is quite dumb, of course it is possible. I might not be recommended for various reasons, I agree, but not possible?! And considering that I only want to replace a very specific string with another string, I see no reason to not use sed / regexes.

Comment: @oguzismail: I tried that, still no success. `+ sed -e '\^<!-- cssintern -->^' -e '{r /home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/1_txt_in/##_frags_struct_##/styles1.css.frag' -e d -e '}' -i '/home/vici/Dropbox/MyFiles/work/___rug/_!_workarea/2_txt_out/aca/books_1by1/independent/12.17 - Acatistul Sfantului Proroc Daniel.frag.html'
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: missing command
`. Command line: `sed -e '\^<!-- cssintern -->^' -e '{r '"$src_dir_frags_struct/styles1.css.frag" -e 'd' -e '}' -i "$out_dir_aca/books_1by1/independent/$(basename "$aca_frag").html"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The syntax is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) (comment mine):

```
[2addr] {editing command       # No newline between '[2addr]' and '{'!
editing command
...
}
```

Where `[2addr]` is for example the `/filtering/` expressions. The option `-e` does (emphasis mine):

> If any -e or -f options are specified, the script of editing commands shall initially be empty. The commands specified by each -e or -f option shall be added to the script in the order specified. When each addition is made, **if the previous addition (if any) was from a -e option, a <newline> shall be inserted before the new addition**. The resulting script shall have the same properties as the script operand, described in the OPERANDS section.

When there is a newline between `[2addr]` and `{` the script is invalid:

```
$ sed -e '/something/' -e '{' -e '}' /dev/null
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: missing command
$ sed '
/something/
{
}' /dev/null
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown command: `
'
```

Putting the `{` with `[2addr]` fixes the problem as it removes the newline:

```
$ sed -e '/somethimg/{' -e '}' /dev/null
```

So put it with the filtering expression:

```
sed
   -e '\^<!-- cssintern -->^{'
   #   ^^                  ^^ here '{' is with /expression/
   # or just: -e '/<!-- cssintern -->/{'
   -e 'r blabla/styles1.css.frag'
   -e d
   -e '}' -i 'blabla/12.17 - Acatistul Sfantului Proroc Daniel.frag.html'
```

Should be fine.

Comment: Of course there is still no reason to use `^` instead of `/` in the first regex.

Comment: Also, probably merge the two scripts into one.