# sed - replace pattern with content of file, while the name of the file is the pattern itself

Tags: bash, sed

Starting from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65637524/10988580), I have another one. If I make this work, I can just delete several lines of script :D

I want to  transform this line:

```
sed -i -r -e "/$(basename "$token_file")/{r $token_file" -e "d}" "$out_dir_rug"/rug.frag
```

into  this line:

```
sed -i -r -e "/(##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##)/{r $out_dir_frags_rug/\1" -e "d}" "$out_dir_rug"/rug.frag
```

The idea is the following. Originally (the first line), I searched for some patterns, and then replaced  those patterns with their  associated files. The names of the files are the patterns themselves.

Eample:

Pattern: `##_foo_##`

File name: `##_foo_##`

Content of file `##_foo_##`:

```
first line of foo text
second line of foo text
```

so the text

```
bar
##_foo_##
bar
```

would become

```
bar
first line of foo text
second line of foo text
bar
```

---

In  my second  attempt, I used `sed` for both locating the patterns, and for the actual replacement.

The result is that the patterns are found, but replaced with pretty much nothing.

**Is `sed`  supposed to be able to do the replacement I want? If yes, how should I change my command?**

---

Note: a file usually has several different patterns (I call them tokens), and the same pattern may appear more than one time.

So an input file might look like:

```
bar
bar
##_foo_##
bar
##_haa_##
bar
##_foo_##
and so on
```

---

I already tried to replace the `/` in the  address with `,`, to no useful result. Escaping the `/` in the path to  `\/` also does not help.

I verified that the path to the replacement files is good by adding the next line, just before the `sed`:

```
echo "$out_dir_frags_rug"
```

Comment: `The names of the files are the patterns themselves.` then do not use `sed` for that. Use `awk`. Or `python`. Or any other templating solution.

Answer (score 2):

> The names of the files are the patterns themselves.

If you need anything "dynamic", then `sed` is not enough for it. As `sed` can't do "eval" - can't reinterpret the content of pattern buffer or hold buffer as commands (that would be amazing!) - you can't use the line as part of the command.*

You can use bash, untested, written here:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^##_([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)_## ]]; then
       cat "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
       printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done < inputfile
```

but that would be slow - bash is slow on reading lines. A similar design could be working in a POSIX shell with POSIX tools, by replacing `[[` bash extension with some `grep` + `sed` or `awk`.

An `awk` would be waaaaaaay faster, something along, also untested:

```
awk '/^##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##$/{
        gsub(/^##_/, "", $0);
        gsub(/_##$/, "", $0);
        file = $0
        while (getline tmp < (file)) print tmp;
        next
     }
     {print}
' inputfile
```

That said, for your specific problem, instead of reinventing the wheel and writing yet another templating and preprocessing tool, I would advise to concentrate on researching existing solutions. A simple `cpp` file with the following content can be preprocessed with C preprocessor:

```
bar
bar
#include "foo"
bar
#include "haa"
bar
#include "foo"
and so on
```

It's clear to anyone what it means and it has a very standarized format and you also get get all the `#ifdef` conditional expressions, macros and macro functions that you can use - but you can't start lines with `#`, dunno if that's important. For endless ultimate templating power, I could recommend `m4` from the standard unix commands.

* You can however with GNU sed execute the content of replacement string inside `s` command in shell with `e` flag. I did forget about it when writing this answer, as it's rarely used and I would strongly advise against using `e` flag - finding out proper quoting for the subshell is hard (impossible?) and it's very easy to abuse it. Anyway, the following could work:

```
sed -n '/^##_\(.*\)_##$/!{p;n;}; s//cat \1/ep'
```

but with the following input it may cause harm on your system:

```
some input file
##_$(rm /)_##
   ^^^^^^^ - will be executed in subshell and remove all your files
```

I think proper quoting would be something along (untested):

```
sed -n '/^##_\(.*\)_##$/!{p;n;}; s//\1/; '"s/'/'\\\\''/g; p; s/.*/cat '&'/ep"
```

but I would go with existing tools like `cpp` or `m4` anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes me unhappy that `sed` chokes at this "minor" modification of my script. I  will try to follow your advice and use `grep` + `sed` before starting to learn `awk`, since I am already familiar with these tools (even  though  I still need  to learn a lot).

Comment: Neee, learn `awk`, it's extremely easy, simple and powerful utility. You can do in `awk` what you can do in `grep` and `sed` and a loooooot more.

Comment: Maybe in the next "episode", after I have something working. Thanks for the  advice, though ;)

Comment: « *sed can't do "eval" - can't reinterpret the content of pattern buffer or hold buffer as commands (that would be amazing!)*  »... Well, prepare to be amazed because GNU sed can do exactly that :-)

Comment: Sure, you could do `sed 's/.*/sed &/e'`, but that is unreliable and quoting is almost impossible to handle. And `sed` is not meant for that. Hm.. let's add that to answer.

Comment: "but that is unreliable and quoting is almost impossible to handle". Yes, like in any language, be it awk, perl, php, C, Python, etc Nonetheless, functions are provided (system(), popen(), eval()...) and of course it must be used with caution, with a properly sanitized input. Seriously, are you telling us you are enable to do with sed the same check `/^##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##$/` you do in your answer in bash and awk? I wonder what you expected with your "that would be amazing" That sed would provide a magically safe version of the `e`-val? _This_ would be amazing, but _this_ is asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

## With `sed`

Yes, this is possible with GNU `sed`.

With this input file `input.txt`:

```
= bar =
##_foo_##
= bar2 =
##_foo_##
= bar3 =
```

And the `##_foo_##` file you gave in your question, the command

```
sed -E '
    /^##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##$/ {
        s|^|cat ./|
        e
    }
' input.txt
```

... will yield:

```
= bar =
first line of foo text
second line of foo text
= bar2 =
first line of foo text
second line of foo text
= bar3 =
```

This command can also be shortened to this one-liner:

```
sed -E '/^##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##$/ s|^|cat ./|e' input.txt
```

### Explanation

GNU `sed` has a special command `e` that executes the command found in pattern space and then replaces the content of the pattern space with the output of the command.

When the above program encounters a line matching your pattern `##_file_##`, it prepends `cat ./` to the pattern space and executes it with `e`.

The `s/.../.../e` command is a shortened version that does exactly the same, the command being executed only if a successful substitution occured.

Contrary to what KamilCuk says in their answer, both `sed` commands above are perfectly safe and don't need any escaping/quoting because they are executed on a known harmless pattern that cannot be tricked to execute anything else than the expected `cat`.

Of course, this is designed to work with that `##_file_##` pattern you gave in your question. Allowing spaces or other fancy characters in your pattern may break things since they might be interpreted by the shell.

---

## With `awk`

Here is the equivalent with `awk`:

```
awk '
    /^##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##$/ {
        system("cat ./" $0)
        next
    }

    1
' input.txt
```

This command can also be shortened to this one-liner:

```
awk '! /^##_[_a-zA-Z0-9]+_##$/ || system("cat ./" $0)' input.txt
```

### Explanation

This is very similar to the `sed` commands above: when `awk` meets the pattern `##_file_##` it builds the corresponding `cat` command and executes it with `system()` then it skips to the next input line with `next`. Lines that don't match the pattern are printed as is (the `1` line).

Of course, the command being interpreted by the shell, the same caveat applies here: both `awk` commands are perfectly safe and don't need any escaping/quoting as long as your pattern stays that simple.